# codec for an enum field with spotify/json

Tags: c++, json

I'm using [`spotify/json`](https://github.com/spotify/spotify-json) to serialize some of my objects to JSON.
One of the objects has an `enum class` field.

The library has one [codec for the enumeration](https://github.com/spotify/spotify-json/blob/master/doc/api.md#enumeration_t), however it says "default_codec support: No; the convenience builder must be used explicitly", so how can I integrate the conversion of my enum field?

```
enum class LogLevel {...};

class LogEntry
{
public:
    std::string node_name;
    LogLevel level;
    std::string message;
    int64_t time_usec;
};

#include <spotify/json.hpp>

namespace spotify {
namespace json {

using T = LogEntry;

template <>
struct default_codec_t<T>
{
    static codec::object_t<T> codec()
    {
        auto codec = codec::object<T>();
        codec.required("node_name", &T::node_name);
        codec.required("level", &T::level); // how to cast here?
        codec.required("message", &T::message);
        codec.required("time_usec", &T::time_usec);
        return codec;
    }
};

} // namespace json
} // namespace spotify
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by declaring the `level` field as:

```
union {
    LogLevel level;
    int level_int;
};
```

and using the `int` part of the union in the codec:

```
codec.required("level", &LogEntry::level_int);
```